# Autofac and Cross-AppDomain Proxies

Tags: c#, proxy, appdomain, autofac, realproxy

I am trying to register a cross-AppDomain proxy with Autofac.

The concrete type represented by the proxy implements the interface IServiceHost. Thus, the proxy should also, in order to allow calls to the proxy using that interface to work.

I try to register the proxy with Autofac, by doing:

```
void Initialize(IServiceHost host)
{
    Host = host;

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterInstance(host)
        .As<IServiceHost>()
        .SingleInstance();

    Scope = builder.Build();
}
```

However, on the `builder.Build()` call, I get:

> ArgumentException
>
> The type 'System.MarshalByRefObject' is not assignable to service 'Treadmarks.Core.ServiceBase.IServiceHost'.

However, `host` is **definitely** an `IServiceHost`, since it isn't null and it comes from a strongly typed method argument.

Can anyone explain how I can register the proxy properly?

Comment: So `host` does not implement `IServiceHost`? In that case it is not a Autofac problem.

Comment: @Steven I specifically said that the proxied type *does* implement `IServiceHost`, and so thus the proxy must implement it also.

Comment: Autofac checks whether `host` is a `IServiceHost` and because it is not, Autofac throws an exception.

Comment: @Steven It definitely is an `IServiceHost` -- the variable is a method argument and is passed in as `IServiceHost host`.

Comment: @Steven I edited the question; does this convince you that it is definitely an IServiceHost and the issue is in Autofac?

Comment: Note, 'SingleInstance' doesn't make sense with 'RegisterInstance'. After all, there will always only be that one instance. Don't think it has anything to do with your error though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a lambda with the  `.Register()` method, rather than `.RegisterInstance()`, to work around this.